# Module exports say undefined between two js file

Tags: javascript

I am still beginner in javascript, So sorry if i am doing something silly. I have two file as below

file test.js

```
var test2=require("./test2");

const Type='TYPE';
const Brand='BRAND';

module.exports={    
Type,Brand
}

function see(){
console.log(test2.details);
}
see()
```

file test2.js

```
var test=require("./test.js")
const details="for testing";

module.exports={
details
}

function doTest(){
console.log(test.Type)
}

doTest()
```

and it gives me follwing outputs where it says undefined.

[image]

why it is giving output as undefined?

Comment: You use require once with **.js** and once without. That looks off to me

Comment: Please do remove circular dependecies, as it can cause the issue.
Your import `test2` in `test` and vice versa.

Comment: You have a circular dependency. `test` requires `test2`, and vice-versa. As soon as I fix that, the `undefined` disappears.

Comment: But what is getting wrong there. Can anyone please explain me?

Answer (score 1):

The design pattern you're using is not maintainable, more of incorrect. As suggested by @Sergii Vorobei, remove circular dependency. Circular dependency is the case when two or more files import each other causing unexpected bugs because of recursion.

To answer your question,

```
// test.js

const Type = 'TYPE';
const Brand = 'BRAND';

module.exports={    
   Type,
   Brand
}
```

and

```
// test2.js

var test = require("./test.js")

function doTest() {
   console.log(test.Type, test.Brand)
}

doTest()
```

Keep your code simple.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use :

```
var {type, brand} = require("./test.js")
//do whatever with type, brand
```